# Hyperledger 1.4.4: Private data is not purged

Tags: collections, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, private

I have  a test network with solo orderer and one private data collection. BlockToLive is set to 3. I started to add new entries with putPrivateData and putState. Initially I observed, that the older private entries were purged. However, after a while this is not a case anymore. Old entries stay in private data collection. With this command

```
peer channel fetch newest -o orderer:7050 -c exchange-channel last.block `
```

I am able to see that the block number changes and blockToLive condition should actually be fulfilled.

What could be the reason? Which logs should be checked?

Comment: can you open a JIRA at jira.hyperledger.org/ and attach some logs and a proof?

Comment: Ok. I'll do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time right now to deepdive into this matter. Right now the problem is gone. My feeling is that it is connected with the changed property "blockToLive" (which is not allowed) in collections.config. Even though it is not allowed, the new version of chaincode gets deployed. I mean a new docker container with the latest version of chaincode appears on the peer, but it does not do anything. At the same time a container with the old version processes the transactions. I'll still try later to find the wrong configuration and collect the proof.